# Replicate the generation of random number generators using Seedsequence in cpp

Tags: python, random, seed

I am working on the conversion of Gibb's sampler written in python to cpp. Though the code works fine, there is reproducibility issue. The Python code is able to generate the similar output for any set of seeds wheread cpp code results are inconsistent across different runs.

The following snippet of code is used for generating the random numbers for different iterations in Python:

```
ss=np.random.SeedSequence()
child_states = ss.spawn(n) #n is the number of iterations
for i in range(0,n):   
     inference(child_states[i]); 
def inference(seed):
     child_states = seed.spawn(len(Docs))
     for i in range(len(Docs)):
            seq(seed);
def seq(seed):
     rng = np.random.default_rng(seed)
     for i in range(0,V):
        z=rng.multinomial(................)
```

And following is the snippet tried in c++ using pcg64 object:

```
void inference(){
     pcg_extras::seed_seq_from<std::random_device> seedSource;
     pcg64 rng(seedSource);
     for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
         gsl_rng_set(r, rng());
         for(int j=0;j<V;j++)
             gsl_ran_multinomial(..................)
                
}
```

Is there a way to achieve the same pseudo random number generation steps in CPP?

Modification update:
For a small number of samples, I am able to resolve the reproducibility issue. So what I tried is

```
    std::vector<unsigned int> seed_values(10);
    std::generate(seed_values.begin(), seed_values.end(),        
    std::ref(rd));
    std::seed_seq seq(seed_values.begin(), seed_values.end());
```

generate a set of m seeds and use that to generate m sequences of seeds like this

```
    std::seed_seq seq{seed};
    std::vector<std::uint64_t> seeds(m);
    seq.generate(seeds.begin(), seeds.end());
```

This works fine for a small number of samples but when the number of samples is large, seems that two samples are assigned similar random numbers. Will the number of bits of seed be an issue as the number of bits of seed is at least 128 bits in Python, whereas in cpp it is up to 64 bits.

Comment: _"And following is the snippet tried in cpp"_ no it's not.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to achieve the same pseudo-random number generation steps in C++ as in Python. However, it's important to note that different random number generators may have slightly different behaviors and implementation details across programming languages. Can you also show what you have written in C++ to get  a sense of what you are looking for?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ There's a `std::random_device` in there, it's not python either. It's not a problem with tagging.

Comment: @Eldinur Apologies if I have missed any details. I am not sure about how to implement the Seedsequence part. So, I have used the pcg64 random number generator in c++.

Comment: @AdhithiS Well as mentioned above, there is no C++ code in your answer. Please modify it so we can see what you did. (it does not have to work, it does not have to be perfect. But I want to see C++ code instead of just python code)

Comment: @Eldinur I have updated the code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ you typically initialise the pseudo-random number generators as follows:

```
std::default_random_engine e((std::random_device())());
```

which produces a random number generator with more or less randomly chosen seed.

If you replace this with a fixed seed then you will receive the *identical* sequence of pseudo-random numbers no matter how often you let the compiled programme run; try with e.g.

```
std::default_random_engine e(1012);
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uid(0, 1000);
for(size_t i = 1; i <= 100; ++i)
{
    std::cout << std::setw(3) << uid(e) << (i % 10 ? ' ' : '\n');
}
std::cout.flush();
```

If you parse a command line parameter you could dynamically exchange sequences while still having control over when to receive identical sequences to other programme runs.

C++ comes with quite a number of pre-implemented algorithms and distributions, see [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) – if among these there are the same algorithm and distribution than the ones python uses then there are chances that you even are able to produce identical sequences in both python and C++ for the same seed, but no guarantee for, differences in the details of the implementation might prevent it as well.

Above uses the C++ standard random library (which I'd rather recommend instead of some 3rd party library) as I'm not familiar with PCG library. If you prefer to continue with the latter: That one uses a seed generator, I don't know how often it will call it, though it appears reasonable to me to assume just once. If you now replace `std::random_device` in your code snippet with a custom one you let always return the same predefined seed in its `operator()` (you might adjust a static variable of to control it via command line parameters) then you might again reliably reproduce the same sequences (but you need to test on your own...).

Comment: Thank you so much for the cppreference link. I am able to reproduce the results using  generate function defined in the seed_seq class :)

Comment: For a small number of samples, I am able to resolve the reproducibility issue. So what I tried is  ''' std::vector<unsigned int> seed_values(10);
std::generate(seed_values.begin(), seed_values.end(), std::ref(rd));
std::seed_seq seq(seed_values.begin(), seed_values.end()); ''' generate a set of m seeds and use that to generate m sequences of seeds like this ''' std::seed_seq seq{seed};
    std::vector<std::uint64_t> seeds(m);
    seq.generate(seeds.begin(), seeds.end()); '''

Comment: @AdhithiS I'm not sure what you actually want to achieve... If `rd` indeed is a `std::random_device` as I'd assume from its name then you won't ever be reproducible. You need identical seeds to reproduce identical sequences, thus you would initialise the seed generator with fixed values (or ones you parse from command line parameters) like `std::seed_seq seq({12, 10, 51, 77, 54});`